# Splitting flat file rows to multiple flat files SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm fairly new to SSIS and I'm having a bit of a problem splitting a CSV into multiple files by row.

I have a CSV with multiple rows  - I am trying to split each row into a new flat file and make each column a new line in the flat file.

I currently have a flat file source pumping into a derived column and sorting the data into the format I want. To test this I outputted it into 1 large flat file with multiple rows however I would ideally like to create a file for each row.

I have tried using a for each to loop through but I'm not quite sure how to use it in SSIS.

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a loop, a C# script will do the trick. With blocks defined as:

Source -> [RowCounter into variable `Counter`] -> [Script Task] -> Destination

Script Task:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["Counter"].Value);
Dts.Connections["destinationConnectionName"].ConnectionString = "c:\\yourpath\\" + val.ToString() + ".txt";
```

of course you have to specify readonly parameter: Counter.

This will set the connection name for each row. Combine it with sorting, which you already have.

Comment: This looks close to what I'm looking for but how do I only output row[count] to the file I create. Having trouble implementing the script code - It doesn't like DTS. Thanks

Comment: SSIS is processing data row by row, each one goes through whole Data Flow - From source to dest. That will output each row to the new file.

Comment: I'm using a script component as all of this is inside a DFT - is this incorrect?

Comment: It will only let me use a script component inside the DFT which uses the above code doesn't work in

Comment: You should be using `Script Task` in DFT. Did you build the script and specify the corrent read only variables?

Comment: I did but the script component seems to be different than a script task. It wont recognise Dts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Multicast Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137701.aspx) in a Data Flow to send each record derived from your Flat File Source to two or more Flat File Destinations.  This may be a more efficient way to use SSIS than using a loop container or a script task.